# Upgrading to a specific redis patch

Tags: installation, apt, redis

I'm new to backend development in general and redis in particular. I'm currently trying out `redis 2.8.4`, but need to upgrade to `redis 2.8.9` in order to leverage the  lexicographical manipulation commands. How do I upgrade to this redis patch?

I originally installed redis-server via `sudo apt-get install redis-server`, and just tried `sudo apt-get install redis-server=2.8.9`, but got `Version '2.8.9' for 'redis-server' was not found`.

Even just doing `sudo apt-get install redis-server` yields `redis-server is already the newest version`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find `redis 2.8.9` [here](http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-2.8.9.tar.gz)

**How to install it ?**

**Download**, **extract** and **compile** Redis with:

```
 1. wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-2.8.9.tar.gz
 2. tar xzf redis-2.8.9.tar.gz
 3. cd redis-2.8.9
 4. make
```

As someone said on that [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68576/how-does-one-upgrade-redis-2-2-to-2-4)

> As Redis 2.4 is not in the Repository for testing or unstable, you
>   will need to compile it manually. Just uninstall the old version of
>   Redis (via apt), and compile the new one.

Comment: In doing so, would (i) the keys in my current redis DB(s) be flushed? (ii) would the redis-server restart? I ask because I need to know how critical taking the dump of the db would be when doing this. Thanks for the blazingly fast response btw, very redis-y!

Comment: Btw mine is just a patch-level change, i.e. going from `2.8.4` to `2.8.9`. The post about 2.2 to 2.4 wouldn't apply, no?

Comment: Not sure about this, I don't think so since there is a specific command for that which is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851909/how-do-i-delete-everything-in-redis

Let me look into it see what can I found :)

Comment: I did find that thread https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-and-restore-your-redis-data-on-ubuntu-14-04 that explain how to back up and restore your redis data, probably the wise choice before doing an upgrade (you never know what can go wrong !)